# Dynamically Render Unstrutured JSON Data in an html Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, html

I have some data that is available in json, in this format

```
"card": {
  "id": "ybLaK64d",
  "type": "VISA",
  "last4": "1881",
  "expMonth": 11,
  "expYear": 17,
  "dateCreated": 1429515587898,
  "cardEntryMode": "E_COMMERCE"
},
"disputed": false,
"amount": 1000,
"settlementAmount": 1000,
"tagPurchase":true, //optional
```

the card object structure is fixed, but there could be up to 10 extra optional fields. I want to render this in an html table dynamically, such that rows with missing fields are marked `undefined`. my front end is angularjs, pulling in the json via `$http`. my final table would be something like this

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>card.id</td>
      <td>card.type</td>
      .
      .
      .
     <td>card.cardentrymode</td>
     <td>disputed</td>
     <td>amount</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      .
      .
      .
  </tbody>
<table>
```

how can I get this done, so that the table is dynamically created, is updated in real time and so that the table headers are created from the record with the most optional fields?

Comment: The short answer is: not easily.
What you'd need to do it process ALL of the data and determine the common fields, generate an HTML template from that information, store that template in $templateCache under and generated name, display the template with an ng-include where the generated name is a value on the scope.
When you need a new template then store it under a different name in the cache and update the scope value with its value.

Comment: the data is a real time feed, so the table should be able to adjust dynamically to the new data, therefore processing all the data at once is not possible..

Comment: One strategy would be to keep a record of the feed in javascript, and to (re)process *all data to date* every time new data arrives - ie. always re-create the table from scratch. This will simplify the adding of new column(s) when they arise. Otherwise, you would have to add columns to an existing table, which is possible but slightly awkward.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue in the past.

My solution included having a table with all the possible columns. Otherwise a really bad UX will result from an ever-changing column name.

So you must know in advance the name of ALL the fields you want to display.

At first load of the data you fill an object that follows YOUR desired structure, assigning "N/A" for missing data.

Then, each time a new set of data is fetched, you update your own object with the new data.

As Enzey pointed out in his comment, it's not easy. And changing the column name doesn't really help consuming the data, which is the end goal of a table! :)